# Mapper, normalizer or transformer?

Tags: javascript, nestjs, nest

*everything below is happening outside controller scope*

I'm working with nest and have incoming data structure like 
`{id: 1, username: 'user', email: 'gogo@gmail.com', age: 23, phone: '3123132', ...and many other fields}`

But for my app there is needed only fields 'id', 'username' and 'email'. Other fields should be omitted, and 'username' should be changed to 'name'.

Where can I do this logic?
Create something like "user.transformer.ts"? Or "user-transformer.service.ts"?
Or use not "transformer", but "mapper" or "normalizer"?

Because I couldn't find any examples of such cases not in scope of controller (where all can be done with nest "magic", dto and so on).

Comment: If it's an isolated context, pick your poison :)

Answer (score 0):

You can create Nestjs Interceptor they are used to modifying incoming request and outgoing response, and apply that interceptor to the controller method or controller using @UseInterceptor Decorator.

You can read more about Interceptor [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors)

Comment: everything in my question is happening outside the controller scope